# Retrieve Mechanical Soup results after submitting a form

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanicalsoup

I am struggling to retrieve some results from a simple form submission. This is what I have so far:

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.set_verbose(2)
url = "https://www.dermcoll.edu.au/find-a-derm/"
browser.open(url)

form = browser.select_form("#find-derm-form")
browser["postcode"] = 3000
browser.submit_selected()

form.print_summary()
```

Where do these results end up...?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [MechanicalSoup FAQ](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html), you shouldn't use this library when dealing with a dynamic JavaScript-enabled form, which seems to be the case for the website in your example.

Instead, you can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) in combination with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (and a little bit of help from [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)) to achieve your desired result. A short example would look like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# set up the Chrome driver instance using webdriver_manager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# navigate to the page
driver.get("https://www.dermcoll.edu.au/find-a-derm/")

# find the postcode input and enter your desired value
postcode_input = driver.find_element_by_name("postcode")
postcode_input.send_keys("3000")

# find the search button and perform the search
search_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("search-btn.location_derm_search_icon")
search_button.click()

# get all search results and load them into a BeautifulSoup object for parsing
search_results = driver.find_element_by_id("search_result")
search_results = search_results.get_attribute('innerHTML')
search_results = BeautifulSoup(search_results)

# get individual result cards
search_results = search_results.find_all("div", {"class": "address_sec_contents"})

# now you can parse for whatever information you need
[x.find("h4") for x in search_results]  # names
[x.find("p", {"class": "qualification"}) for x in search_results]  # qualifications
[x.find("address") for x in search_results]  # addresses
```

While this way may seem more involved, it's a lot more robust and can be easily repurposed for many more situations where MechanicalSoup falls short.

Comment: (1) Thank you. I am not very familiar with HTML - the last three list comprehensions are empty. Am I supposed to pass my own tags (2) What method do you use to locate the tags of interest?

Comment: @GlaceCelery - they might be empty because the page didn't have enough time to load the form results, I'd give it a couple of seconds between clicking the search button and finding the search results, or just add a `time.sleep(10)` to do it automatically;
to get tags of interest I just right-click > inspect the elements and have a look at the resulting HTML in the side pane.

Comment: Still no luck with time.sleep(10). `search_results.text` seems to work however

Comment: Ah - It worked with a longer sleep. Another issue: how do I obtain the Google map coordinates for each item?

Comment: @GlaceCelery Glad to hear it. Coordinates are a different problem since they're not readily available to scrape from your website. I'd suggest using the addresses you get from this step and plugging them into something like [geopy](https://pypi.org/project/geopy/). Hope it's been helpful!